# How to cancel a Quartz job instead of enqueue in case of @DisallowConcurrentExecution

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quartz Enques a job(JobA) if same job(JobA) instance is in execution in case of @DisallowConcurrentExecution. But I want to cancel that job instead of enqueuing it up for execution

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using TriggerListeners, but with this solution you can't have triggers that fire multiples jobs

```
class CustomTriggerListener extends TriggerListenerSupport {

    private JobExecutionContext lastJobExecutionContext;

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        boolean vetoExecution = false;
        if (lastJobExecutionContext == null) {
            lastJobExecutionContext = context;
        } else {
            boolean lastJobIsDone = lastJobExecutionContext.getJobRunTime() >= 0;

            if (lastJobIsDone) {
                lastJobExecutionContext = context;
            } else {
                vetoExecution = true;
            }
        }

        return vetoExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomTriggerListener";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check if the job is already running and if yes then interrupt this job

```
for (int i = 0; i < scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().size(); i++) {
    if(scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().get(i).
                        getJobDetail().getKey().getName().equals(jobName)) {
            scheduler.interrupt(new JobKey(jobName, "group1"));
        }
    }
```